# My power/battery indicator applet is a red exclamation point

Tags: icons, power-management, indicator, mate

I've just upgraded from 14.10 to 15.10 and my power indicator applet is messed up. It shows up on my panel as a red circle with an exclamation point in it. I've tried it with different icon themes, and it shows up in some as an orange triangle. The laptop battery is fully-charged and my mouse battery is at 90%. Before, when my laptop battery was low, the icon was a normal battery, but empty and red. I've reinstalled indicator-power, and that didn't fix it. Any ideas?

[image: The battery applet is a red circle with an exclamation point inside.]

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the "You need to reboot to ensure installation of up-to-date software. Click here." hint that shows up after a software update if you should reboot. Click it. You need to reboot. Save stuff first.

Comment: No joy, it's still red.

Comment: I hate to be obvious, but have you checked your Power/Battery?

Comment: Yep, they're normal.

Comment: I'm getting a red (!) for my keyboard layout switching applet; I suspect this might just be a generic "ubuntu got confused while drawing the icon" situation.